# Is `Tru64 UNIX` open source?

Tags: history

Is `Tru64 UNIX` an open source/free or commercial system? Does it work on 32-bit platform? and what are its features in compare with `*BSD` & `Linux` system?

Comment: Try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tru64_Unix to start with.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: tried it before, my English is not so good. I did not understand it very well, because of that I came here to ask.

Comment: Here you get answers in english, so not much different from wikipedia. You can try Google translation services.

Comment: @enzotib: Simple english is better than machine translation.

Comment: @Adban: There is a [Simple English Wikipedia](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) site. There isn't a Simple English page for Tru64 UNIX, but you might find the site useful in the future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is HP's commercial 64-bit UNIX operating system (based on the Mach kernel - which Mac OS X is also based on)

It is for the Alpha instruction set architecture only - although there was a short lived Intel port.

Broadly speaking, usage is similar to many other *nixes, but the location of various config files, executables etc may be not where you expect.

Comment: Actually it is one of HP's UNIXes (the other being HP-UX).

Answer (score 8):

Tru64 is a commercial Unix system. It wass originally called OSF/1, OSF standing for [Open Software Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Software_Foundation). It is original in that it is neither based on AT&T source code ([System V](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_System_V)) nor on [BSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD), the two major Unix flavor. The OSF was led by DEC as an attempt to compete against System V which they felt excluded companies other than AT&T and Sun.

Only DEC made significant use of OSF/1. DEC's OSF/1 was known as Digital Unix (from [Digital Equipment Corporation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Equipment_Corporation), and it was the operating system shipped with most of DEC's workstations (there was aslo a version of Windows NT for some low-to-mid-end Alphas). first based on [MIPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture) processors (32-bit), then later on [Alpha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEC_Alpha). Because Alphas were at the time the only affordable 64-bit platforms (not as cheap as a PC, but cheaper than “big iron”), and as part of the rebranding of DEC products after [Compaq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compaq) [bought DEC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Equipment_Corporation#Final_years) in 1998.

In 2002, [Hewlett-Packard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hewlett-Packard) bought Compaq. HP had its own 64-bit platforms (the traditional [PA-RISC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PA-RISC), the new high-end [Itanium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itanium) and more recently the cheaper [AMD64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64)) and its own Unix brand ([HP-UX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP-UX)) plus Linux, so it had no use for either Alpha or OSF/1.

While OSF/1 did have innovative features at the time it was developped, none were licensed for reuse in other systems, as far as I know. Nowadays I think any worthwhile feature has been imitated by others already. HP has not released the OSF/1 intellectual property, except for a version of the [AdvFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdvFS) filesystem.

Comment: DG was Data General.  Definitely **not** the same as DEC!!  Also, HP (or Compaq) licensed Tru64's cluster software to Oracle for db clustering.

Comment: Actually, most of the command and utilities were either BSD or AT&T licensed and were ported to the Alpha platform from the Ultrix platform.  Some items such as `ncurses` and `nawk` were directly licensed from USL.

Comment: It would be more factual to state that only DEC made use of the Mach kernel.  Other components of OSF/1 such as CDE, Motif, DCE, and liots more, were used by many companies.

Answer (score 2):

As per the above Wikipedia article `Tru64 UNIX` is a commercial system and it works only on the `DEC Alpha` platform.